# Saving info on a server, and getting it back

Tags: php, ajax, database

On my website i take user input from a form, and add it to a query plugin to output on the screen. Its nice to get the users input, but as soon as i refresh the page, all the input is lost and reset. How can i save the user input so that even when the page is refreshed, the data will stay there for good? can u use my code to show me?

```
<html>
 <head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="textualizer.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

#txtlzr{color:#585856; font-size:50px; width:1200px; height:100px;
margin-left:10%;
margin-top:80px;
font-family:"futura";
position: fixed;
}
 </style>

<body>

   <div id="txtlzr"></div>
    <form action="#" method="post"/>
      <fieldset>
       <label for="kwote">Comment:</label>
       <input class="kwote" type="text" maxlength="40" id="kwote"
         placeholder="Enter a something here."/>
       <lable for="name">Name:</label>
       <input class="name" type="text" maxlength="17" id="name"
         placeholder="Enter your name."/>
       <input class="post" type="button" value="Add comment"
         onclick="add_comment();" />
     </fieldset>
   </form>


 <script language="javascript">
    var COMMENTS_FOR_DISPLAY = new Array('Thanks for the help: nick');

    // Adds a new comment, name pair to the Array feeding textualizer.
    function add_comment() {
      // Retrieve values and add them to Array.
      var new_comment = $('#kwote').val();
      COMMENTS_FOR_DISPLAY.push(new_comment + ': ' + new_name);

      // Reset <input> fields.
      $('#kwote').val('');
      $('#name').val('');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var txt = $('#txtlzr');  // The container in which to render the list

       var options = {
        rearrangeDuration: 5, // Time a character takes to reach its position
        effect: 'random',     // Animation effect the characters use to appear
        centered: true        // Centers the text relative to its container
  }

  txt.textualizer(COMMENTS_FOR_DISPLAY); // textualize it!
  txt.textualizer('start'); // start
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
 </html>
```

Thanks to chris btw for helping me with the input.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge in PHP or databases?

Comment: im pretty sure 99.9% of users wont have the **futura** font....

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot to it other than just the code on the page. You have to have a server-side language and write access into a database server, before you can do anything else.

You might take a look at the [Flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/) or the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) if you've not picked out a language and platform. Both require that you set up a server, but use SQLite, a file-based database system, so you don't need to deal with figuring out database servers yet.

Comment: He tagged it php so I'm assuming he already picked a language.

Comment: Or install XAMMP or LAMP and read some tutorials on PHP + MySQL.

Comment: @Rob, and yet, his question doesn't contain a single reference to or copy-and-paste of any PHP. (Which is probably for the best, I'd rather not aim beginners to PHP.)

Comment: I didn't. He doesn't mention PHP in the comment, nor does he seem to understand the distinction between client-side and server-side coding.

I suggested the two Python tutorials because they use SQLite and won't expose him to a lot of SQL. I'm unaware of PHP tutorials that do the same.

Comment: @sarnold I agree. PHP is good for quick-and-dirty webapps, for hiring cheaper developers, and for distributing your apps to other peoples' servers.

It is not, in my experience, an ideal language through which to learn web development.

Comment: i know a very small about of php, not enough to accomplish what i want. What should i learn that can get this done? i don't know why my question got a minus, i obviously don't know a lot about this stuff, thats why I'm asking.

Comment: PHP can get it done. The tutorials I recommended above both use Python, which should be fairly easy to learn on your machine but are harder to deploy on the web (generally speaking).

If you're set on PHP, the I say you should choose a framework and go with it. I've not been in that world for a while, but a couple of years ago CodeIgniter and CakePHP were the big dogs.

Comment: Oh - while I didn't issue the downvote, you likely got it because it fit the criteria: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

This information is readily available, and shouldn't have been hard to find via Google.